# Compiling Protobufs and Libyara with VC 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to compile a program that uses both libyara and protobufs using VC 2013. I statically compiled the libyara library and it compiles nicely into my program. Once I add the header files for my protobufs things go badly... fast. The issue I'm having relates to what appears to be incorrect headers, but I'm going to assume that the MS supplies header files are correct. Is there a trick here that I'm missing? This is a partial output from the compile:

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xtgmath.h(214): warning C4602: #pragma pop_macro : 'new' no previous #pragma push_macro for this identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xtgmath.h(215): warning C4193: #pragma warning(pop) : no matching '#pragma warning(push)'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xtgmath.h(216): warning C4161: #pragma pack(pop...) : more pops than pushes
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\cmath(23): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'abs'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\cmath(23): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\cmath(23): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'acos'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\cmath(23): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'asin'
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this? Is this related to the mixture of the C library (libyara) and the c++ library (protobuf)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it is an issue with mixing C and C++ code. The solution was to change the file extension for my .c files to .cpp so that everything is viewed as C++ by MSVC.